# Train Travel advice Lisbon -> Krakow

Tags: trains, europe, eu, routes

Can anyone advise me on the best route for traveling via train from Lisbon -> Krakow? Is there some site where I can book the train tickets or search for such routes? I googled around, but I cannot find any conclusive results on the route and suggestions.

Comment: A quick search on german site bahn.de says it takes between 50 to 60 hours. You want to stay somewhere inbetween?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Flying will be much cheaper and much faster.  Is this for "experience" ? Any route recommendation would be dependent on what you actually want to get out of this?

Comment: I can't cite a source, but I remember reading a comment last year where someone claimed that if the EU really wanted to cut CO2 emissions, they would have to find a way to make international train journeys easier to search and book, because currently, you have to search and book (almost) every part of the jorney individually. And that was about rather short distances, where trains are competitive (at least wrt time), not about crossing half the continent.

Comment: @Sabine It should definitely advertised more, but for searching the German bahn.de website is pretty good. It also lets you book some of the itineraries but that can get tricky for complicated routes.

Comment: a bus might be quicker https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Lisbon/Krak%C3%B3w

Comment: Most likely, an Interrail or Eurail ticket (depending if you are a EU/non-EU citizen) will save you some money.

Comment: AlanBirtles Sabine, you both highlighted the problem. Trains are the most environment-friendly, but aren't yet suitable in Europe for looooooooong-hauls because of 1) schedules (i.e. no serious long-haul train) 2) prices on the high-speed routes and no real competition against coaches, which in the end travel faster despite their offensively slow speeds. Solution will be a cheaper, high-speed and trans-national EU rail network covering longer distances than current services

Comment: You want the "best" route, but don't define what criteria you would consider "best". Are you looking for cheapest, fastest, most scenic, fewest changes, fewest stops, most "convenient" (define "convenient"), or something else?. Without knowing these criteria, "best" is purely opinion and would get your question closed on many SE sites.

Comment: @FreeMan -Sorry, best meaning, "fastest". Doesn't have to be scenic or the cheapest. Fastest route :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I checked the [German rail planner](https://www.bahn.com/en), which is mostly pretty good, and it comes with results of 55 to 60 hours, with two 'change trains' in the night which basically leaves you stranded on a station from around midnight till the first train in the morning.

There might be 'once a week' or 'only in times of high demand' trains that go through the night. And with 8 to 16 changes, duration from 10 minutes to 8 hours (in the night.)

Besides having it check from start to finish, you can also look on a map and find a place where you would like to overnight (or stay longer) and have the planner find travels from the start to that station and from that station to your finish, try it out for several locations and see whether you get better results (with or without a longer stop there.)

The German rail planner will also sell you many tickets in Europe, but you will have to call them to find out whether they can sell you the tickets and if so, for how much.

When traveling to and from England, or through Paris, [The Man in Seat 61](https://seat61.com) will often help. And the German planner has you going through Paris, so you can use that site to see what they have to [(London) Paris Lisbon](https://www.seat61.com/Portugal.htm#london-to-lisbon-by-train) and [(London) Paris Krakow](https://www.seat61.com/Poland.htm), and see if they know some night trains.
As mentioned in a comment by @Berend, the site even has a page on which you can find [how to travel from Lisbon to Krakow](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Lisbon.htm#Lisbon_to_Amsterdam), but you will have to scroll down the page quite a bit.
I see this site now also sells tickets, and again I am not sure whether they can sell you this.

There are more sites/travel agencies which specialize in train travel and if you speak either Polish or Portuguese I would try to find one in the country on one end of the journey where you speak the language.

Looking on google maps, to find a nice stopover I happened to have it on public transport and they find a combination of trains and buses which takes 'only' 40 hours.

(I am not connected with the sites I linked to, just a user of them.)

Comment: Seat 61 even has a dedicated section describing Lisbon to Krakow, see https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Lisbon.htm#Lisbon_to_Amsterdam

Comment: The Lisbon to Paris stage used to be a lot easier, but the [Sud Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Express) sleeper train between Lisbon and the connection to the TGV at Irun/Hendaye on the Spanish-French border was suspended at the start of the Covid pandemic and seems unlikely to return.

Answer (score 2):

Its not tricky at all, it just takes a while. I lived south of there for a bit in Lagos on the Mediterranean coast.  Made the rail trip to Prague once and to Amsterdam twice.  It's been a few years but believe its still similar.

It's going to take a while cause you have to change trains a few times, (luckily they usually have connections timed really well). I would usually just wing it & if I hit any major delay from a sold out train or something, it would be somewhere like Madrid, Barcelona, Paris, or Amsterdam where I could easily find a cheap hostel for a night.

My route was-

- slow train up the coast to Porto, then 2 options from there-

  1. train to Madrid followed by the high speed overnight to Paris
  2. train to Barcelona to catch the other (faster) high speed train.

Once you get to the Paris Nord station you can get east to a hub like Amsterdam fairly quickly where you can catch trains &/or tour buses to Eastern countries like Poland, or Czech Republic.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the overnight train from Madrid to Paris? Does this still exist?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Express apparently it was ended at covid but it was planned to be withdrawn. Another was one withdrawn much earlier. https://www.businesstraveller.com/news/2013/12/16/elipsos-sleeper-train-withdrawn-from-service/